# Scala parser: how to match all the remaining part of the string regardless of whitespace?

Tags: scala, parsing, wildcard

I want to parse the first half of the string by a combined parser and use the remaining part of the string as a parameter (e.g. parsing "create abc as select * from apache", can results in "select * from apache" being used as a parameter), so I wrote 2 parsers based on this article:

https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Parser+Combinators--Getting+Started

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {
  def first: Parser[String] = "create" ~> "abc" <~ "as"

  def second: Parser[String] = """.*""".r ^^ { _.toString }

  def parser = first ~ second
}
```

But the implicit type cast fails, looks like this is a deprecated/abandoned syntax,. so what's the easiest way to achieve this in  Scala 2.10.x?

Comment: What fails and how? Your code compiles and works correctly on Scala 2.11.

Comment: This is the error information:
value ^^ is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex
[ERROR]   protected def remainingStrParser: Parser[String] = """.*""".r ^^ { _.toString }

Comment: BTW I'm using Spark 2.10.5, the article was published long before it, so I would be surprised if it works in 2.11.x